# Checkbox with User Stamp when changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, date-time, user, user-controls

I am still a beginner in SharePoint and am looking for some guidance (I can do this in Excel, but can't figure out how to do it in SharePoint).

**FYI - I am stuck using SharePoint online (not Designer) and InfoPath form builder only.  Please do not reference Designer or coding/scripting that cannot be accessed via Online or InfoPath in your response.**

I have a checkbox that, when checked, identifies the record as being audited.  I have a secondary field that captures the timestamp of when the box was checked "Yes".  How can I stamp the user who updated the field?  I can't seem to identify the variable for the formula for user.  I tried the following formula but it did not work as UserName isn't a function in SharePoint.  Is there a similar function variable that when Yes/No is changed to Yes, it will stamp the user who made the change?:

> =If([Yes/No]="Yes", UserName(),"")>

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Bill

**UPDATE:** In InfoPath, I found the "Rule" to populate User Name if the Yes/No = "Yes", but it's not populating a User Name in the User Name field.  Should my "User Stamp" column type be changed?  I currently have it as "Single Text".